Javascript to Python in Adobe Illustrator
I'm trying to get Python to run with a script in Illustrator so that Illustrator will ask the user to enter a number and then create a barcode in 128code with Python and then save it somewhere.
It's not working. Help.
Here is the JS code for the Illustrator:
var idToSearch = prompt('Please enter an ID to search', '');
var pythonScriptPath = "passbar.py";
var fileRef = new File(pythonScriptPath);
fileRef.execute(idToSearch);


Code for the Python.
import sys
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
import os

arg1 = sys.argv[1]
passport = arg1
code128 = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
my_barcode = code128(passport, writer=ImageWriter())
custom_path = ("C:\\Desktop\\python\\barcode.png")
my_barcode.save(custom_path)


"It's not working" is not very specific as to what is not working. Does the Javascript fail to run the python? Does the barcode fail to be produced correctly? What exactly is the problem?

apologies, when I run the script it will prompt the user to enter the number. after that it will display the python code in the editor.

To run a python code via .execute() Windows should be configurated respectively. The method .execute() imitates pressing the Enter key in the Explorer windows. Most likely current configuration means to open some editor app whenever you press Enter on a py-file. So you have two options: to change the Windows configuration (it should rune command like: python your_file.py, or compile the py-code into a executive file *.exe (google it) and run the exe-file instead.

Thank you, I will look into this and see what I can do.
